# Floating Action Button doesn't work

Tags: android

I've added floating action button to my app, and it app crashes with an error:

```
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Button works well on Android 7(tested using Nexus 5 emulator, api 24 and 25), but doesn't work with API 23, or less. As i understood from the documentation, FAB should work fine with this version of Android. How can i fix this bug? Below is my FAB code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/float_btn"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/category_family"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

And Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.immutables:gson:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used wrong attribute

**change below :**

`android:backgroundTint="@color/category_family"`

**TO**

`app:backgroundTint="@color/category_family"`